# Django: Difference between using class and method based view

Tags: django, django-views

I am concerned about whether having less code is the only benefit of using `class-based views` or they have also **runtime benefits**?

Answer (score 1):

They're the tiniest bit slower due to more mangling occurring before they get to actual view code, but that's far outweighed by the ease of use and reuse for code time.